# Model events according to service internal domain model, or a shared model?

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, microservices, event-programming

We have a system built on microservices with 50-100 different services. Previously most servcie-to-service communication was done with direct REST API calls, but we are shifting to a event based architecture (for this question I have simplified the setup a bit)

My question is related to how to model the events between two parts of the system.

We have **Creation** where a user can create content, and **Publishing** where a user can publish the created content. Each part is handled by separate development teams. Further, each part is split up into several services, for example **PublishingScheduling** which does scheduling of when a specific *Batch* of *Content* should be published and **PublishingIntegration** which contains logic for sending a batch of content to different 3rd parties.

Now, a service within the **Creation** needs to know which content is published, and also which *Batch* it was part of. In simple terms, *Content* with id X is part of *Batch* Y.

The domain model within **PublishScheduling** and **PublishingIntegration** is of course not as simple as *Batch* Y contains *Content* X but contains a whole hierarchy of different objects not really relevant to anyone outside of **Publishing**. And this hierarchy is necessary to understand to know which pieces of *Content* is part of which *Batch*es and if its published or not.

What should the events sent out from **PublishScheduling** and **PublishingIntegration** look like? There are two main viewpoints:

- The **Publishing** team argues that because this is microservice architecture, each service should publish events according to their internal domain model. That would mean ~10 different events, for example ContentAssigned(contentId, placeholderId) when *Content* is assigned to a *Placeholder*, BatchCreated(batchId) when a *Batch* is created and so on. If the **Creation** team does not want to put all the logic to decode this, then **Creation** can add a "Anti Corruption Layer"-service that does the translation.
- The **Creation** team argues that since these events are used outside the **PublishScheduling** and **PublishingIntegration** domains, they should contain data structured according to a shared domain. In this case that domain would only contain *Batch* and *Content*, so events like ContentAddedToBatch(batchId, contentId) would be the result.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the best approach here would be for the Publishing team to publish events that follow a shared domain model. This will make it easier for the Creation team to understand and use the events, as well as eliminate the need for a separate "Anti Corruption Layer" service.

While it is important for each service to have its own internal domain model that makes sense within the context of that service, it is also critical to ensure that the events published by a service are structured in a way that other services can easily understand. This will make communication and collaboration between services easier, which is the ultimate goal of using a microservices architecture.